# Combining 2 sql fields in select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am having a bit of a problem with figuring out how to structure my sql query

say i had a table called `user_info` with 2 fields, `firstname` and `lastname`

If `$name = "Bill Jones";`

How would i search the table with the combined `firstname` and `lastname` in the variable name but seperated in the table.

The other problem is that as this is sort of a name search, the user might type just `"bill"` into the input or just `"jones"`, so how do i combine the 2 fields in the query to run a like sql select?

Thanks

Comment: `WHERE CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select firstname , lastname from table where 
  concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%$name%'
```

If `"Bill Jones"` is not same as `"Jones Bill"` 
then consider to use this

```
  select firstname , lastname from table where 
  concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%$name%' OR
  concat(lastname, ' ', firstname) like '%$name%'
```

in your situation use this

```
 select firstname , lastname from table where 
  concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')  OR
  concat(lastname, ' ', firstname) like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```

EDIT:

```
 select firstname , lastname from table1 where 
 concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')  OR
 concat(lastname, ' ', firstname) like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')  OR
 lastname LIKE substring_index($name, ' ',-1) OR
 firstname LIKE substring_index($name, ' ',1)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ed4d9/7)

Comment: Thanks for your answer the error i described below was because i was using the `'` around the select instead of `"` If you dont mind me asking what is the difference between `CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` and just `?`

Comment: @Arken i have used single quotes in LIKE and CONCAT, then you should use double quote s around select

Comment: Ok, it all works great, there is one thing though and i am not sure if this is just to do with the LIKE ability or what, but if the user put in `bill`, then it works great, but if the user puts in `b jones`, then it doesnt return the user_id

Comment: then you must compare by firstname alone or lastname alone. JUST add OR

Comment: @Arken look my last EDIT. there is many probalities , you can just add OR and add other possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
where concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%$name%'
```

That is, concatenate the fields and do the search.  You might also want:

```
where concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%$name%' or
      concat(lastname, ' ', firstname) like '%$name%';
```

Comment: thanks for the help, what does the second query do differently from the first?

Comment: second query should be OR not AND.

Comment: `'SELECT user_id FROM user_profile WHERE concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE ? OR concat(lastname, ' ', firstname) LIKE ?'` This is basically the query i am using but it is throwing a syntax error in my IDE around the `LIKE ? OR`, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the fields first, then search on them.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_info
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname) LIKE '%bill%';
```

**EDIT -** I was too slow!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$search = explode(' ', $name);

$query = "SELECT
    *
FROM
    user_info
WHERE
    firstname LIKE '%" . $search[0] . "%'
    OR firstname LIKE '%" . $search[1] . "%'
    OR lastname LIKE '%" . $search[0] . "%'
    OR lastname LIKE '%" . $search[1] . "%'";
```

Well... the concat way seems to be superior.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this will work for you or not but you could try

Select 
 Whatever 
From user_info 
Where 
 firstname like '%Whatever%' Or lastname like '%Whatever%' Or Concat(firstname, lastname) Like '%Whatever%'

Concat can be different depending on the database you use Concat works, at least, for mySQL. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) your `$name` string, which would create an numerical indexed array, containing the first name and last name.

You would then construct your own sql select query inside php ideally using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)